# iPhone Text random problem?

Tags: iphone, xcode, random

> ```
> -(IBAction)random {
> int text = rand() % 10;
> switch (text) {
> case 0:
> label_name.text = @"text1";
> break;
> case 1:
> label_name.text = @"text2";
> break;
> case 2:
> label_name.text = @"text3";
> break;
> ```

...and so on....

I am using function random for the generation of a random text, but every time I close and start the application I see that it creates or generates the same text.

How can I start always with a random text...no repetition or sequence...?

Comment: well, in both cases you're displaying same text...

Comment: you generate random numbers from 0-9, but only changes the text for 0 and 1 (to the same string). But I guess, what you're looking for is srand(seed); - seed is i.e. the time in millisec or any other unique value

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're not seeding the generator.

I'd use arc4random() in stdlib.h. This utilizes a much more superior algorithm than rand() and you don't have to seed it. Look up this function in the man pages.